# Grails multiple datasource with external config

Tags: grails, datasource, properties-file

Using [this](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources) I've managed to have multiple datasources in my grails app.
However, I also want to define the properties of my datasources from an external file.

I've done it for the default datasource, but i don't know how to name the keys of my property file in order to fill in the black of my new datasource.

Comment: Just to be clear, i don't have multiple datasource based on the enrvironnement, but i use 2 datasource at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you've defined the default datasource's properties in an external `*.properties` file, e.g.

```
dataSource.username=root
dataSource.password=secret
```

You should be able to add the 2nd datasource's properties in the same properties file, e.g. for a datasource named `foo`

```
dataSource_foo.username=root2
dataSource_foo.password=secret2
```